# Spring batch run job and forbid parallel invocations

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I implemented spring batch job that runs every minute. I have this complicated `launchMyCustomJob` method which takes care to run the job and does nothing when the job is currently running basing on jobExecution status field. Since Spring is a IoC container I have impression that I did something wrong. I mean, shouldn't I somehow be able to do the same with some simple configuration ? Job should not be invoked in parallel and if current run is very long, the next one could be immediate or wait whole another `mytask.fixed.rate` period of time.

```
 @Scheduled(fixedRateString = "${mytask.fixed.rate}")
    public void launchJob() throws JobExecutionException {
        launchMyCustomJob();
    }

public void launchMyCustomJob() throws JobExecutionException {
        JobExecution jobExecution = searchLatestInstance();
        if (jobExecution == null || isFinished(jobExection))) {
             jobLauncher.run(myCustomJob, getJobParameter());
        } else if (isRunning(jobExecution)) {
              //do nothing
              log.info("Job is running, cannot start!")
        } else {
            this.jobOperator.restart(jobExecution.getId());
        }
    }


    @Bean
    public Job myCustomJob(Step myCustomStep, JobRepository jobRepository ) {
        JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory = new JobBuilderFactory(jobRepository);
        return jobBuilderFactory.get(MY_JOB_NAME.name())
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .flow(myCustomStep)
                .end()
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    protected Step myCustomStep(JobRepository jobRepository,
                                 PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager,
                                 MyReader myReader,
                                 MyProcessor myProcessor,
                                 MyWriter myWriter ) {
        StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory = new StepBuilderFactory(jobRepository, transactionManager);
        return stepBuilderFactory.get(MY_STEP_NAME).<MyCar, MyCarDto>chunk(10)
                .reader(myReader)
                .processor(myProcessor)
                .writer(myWriter)
                .faultTolerant()
                .skipPolicy(new AlwaysSkipItemSkipPolicy())
                .build();
    }
```

Comment: By design, you can run two different job instances in parallel but you can't run the same job instance while it has a currently running execution (Spring Batch will throw a JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException). So it seems that you are not retrieving the correct job instance/execution when launching jobs (make sure job parameters are the same at launching/retrieval time).

Comment: But I want to forbid execution of two different job instances. Above code works fine I am just asking if the same could be achieved by some configuration of a job/step maybe? I am checking the last instance to check if it finished. If yes, next instance could run. I have @Scheduler expression for every two minutes. It is possible that single processing would take more than two minutes and then the same job is forbidden to start in concurrent thread. Could I do it in another way ?